# nginx upstream's wrong response

Tags: nginx, url

I'm having a problem with my upstream. There is a location block for the web application as below. I'm doing A-B test with this.

```
location / {
   include backend.conf;
}
```

backend.conf

```
proxy_buffering on;
proxy_set_header RIP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
set $session_id_included 'false';

if ($request_uri ~ ';jsessionid=') {
    set $session_id_included 'true';
}

if ($query_string ~ ';jsessionid=') {
    set $session_id_included 'true';
}

proxy_set_header SESSION_ID_INCLUDED $session_id_included;
proxy_pass_header  Set-Cookie;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
proxy_connect_timeout 30;
proxy_read_timeout 30;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404 ;


proxy_set_header Host 'example.com';;
proxy_pass http://backend;
```

This location block is looking at that:

```
upstream backend {
  ip_hash;
  server backend_server_1 max_fails = 0 weight = 80; # old web application
  server backend_server_2 max_fails = 0 weight = 20; # new web application
}
```

Actually, everything works. However, 404 error responses are coming from the backend_server_2 while I connect to the backend_server_1 with ip_hash.

**How do I get 404 error responses from the backend server that I logged in?**

If a user is connected to the backend_server_1 server with ip_hash, 404 errors must come from the backend_server_1 server.

If a user is connected to the backend_server_2 server with ip_hash, 404 errors must come from the backend_server_2 server.

Thanks

Comment: How have you determined that the 404 responses are coming from some particular server? Are you sure the URLs you are using exist on both servers?

Comment: We testing A-B. So the site design are diffirents, old and new site. Always we're facing new site designed 404 error page. When I visit site and seeing backend_server_1 (old site) but always facing backend_server_2 404 error page (new site). 

Also, I have updated the config files.

Comment: @anx you're right, the problem reason by proxy_next_upstream. I have deleted and it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the directive `proxy_next_upstream` contains `http_404`, then an 404 error returned from one upstream server will make nginx pass that request to the next upstream server.

Removing the non-default entry `http_404` will make nginx only serve the 404 answers of the server the user was connected to.

Note that in this case, the `max_fails` parameter is of little significance, because (quoting [nginx proxy module manual](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream)):

> The directive also defines what is considered an unsuccessful attempt of communication with a server. [..] The cases of http_403 and http_404 are never considered unsuccessful attempts.

Meaning you could use *attempt accounting* via `max_fails` to more gracefully deal with one side of your AB-Test malfunctioning. If the 404 concern was the reason for disabling it, reconsider that now.